# Formula for Ratio and Scaling

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to make a formula to suit what I need but im having a hard time. This is the result of missed learning them back then when I was still a student.

I need a formula that fits the situation. The situation is about transferring/exchanging points from $A$ to (become or form into) $B$ whereas the cost of transfer/exchange gets bigger as you try to transfer a larger points. The end should be $B$ is $50\%$ of $A$ when you do a whole of $A$ transferred to become $B$. If it's just an *even* transfer rate, this shouldn't be hard for me.

$100\% \sim 50\%$

$A = 30pts / B = 15pts$ (if you transfer the whole $A$, it will become half of $B$)

Example of transferring:
$$
29/1 \\
28/2 \\
27/3 \\
25/4 \\
15/10 \\
8/13 \\
0/15 \\
$$
And can you tell me what is the called for this kind of scaling/ratio-ing?

I hope the way of my explanation will reach your understanding. Sorry how the way I explained. But if you need clarification, i'll try my best.

Comment: What rule you use? 25/4 you make15/10 where I expected 15/9? 15/10 you make 8/13, why not 8/14? 8/13 you make 0/15 where I would expect 0/17? Are you doing it in steps or you always sartt with the 29/1?

Comment: "What rule you use? 25/4 you make 15/10 where I expected 15/9? 15/10 you make 8/13, why not 8/14? 8/13 you make 0/15 where I would expect 0/17?"
- The rule is yet to be polished. The example i provided is to show you, guys, what im trying to achieve. Don't forget the transfer rate is not even thats why we have 25/4 and not 25/5. 15/10 or 15/9 which of them appear when we have the formula. My problem is making a formula for this kind of situation: when you transfer points from A to B, the greater the number in B the higher the exchange points it requires.

Comment: "Are you doing it in steps or you always start with the 29/1?"
- the number in A is any, the 30 is just an example. If we don't put any points in B, then nothing in A change.

If you nid more clarification, notify me.

Comment: It is not clear if you are looking for a sequence of exchanges. as your list, or how to derive A from stating B. Can B decreased? You use integer values - ant reason for this? Are you attempting to solve a practical problem - what is this original problem.

Comment: sori for the late response, i was finishing this one: http://i747.photobucket.com/albums/xx112/xingha/IMG_20160119_050638_zpsj5kpyego.jpg

the pic is about the rate exchange of A to B using n/100:
the blue number from 0 to 100 is the 100 in the "n/100"
the "n"  is depend on what is the given number in A
the table shows the percentage or rate of exchange

Comment: what number in A is given
the number in B depends on how much number we transferred from A and there is like an exchange rate like in currency
the rate of exchange is getting bigger if you are transferring a larger points
the maximum transfer rate is 200% (so if we have 30 in A then if we use the whole 30 pts, we will have 15 pts in B) and the lowest is 100% (thats why we have 29/1 [A/B])

Comment: the table in the pic is wat ive come up... since i dont know the formula so i just invented a way using logical process